# GREP show lines that contain this but not that

Tags: linux, centos, search, grep

I would like to search for lines that contain "uploaded" but do not contain "09"

Is there a way to do this with grep?

(CentOS 5.6 if it matters).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually chain greps to do this.

```
grep uploaded $file | grep -v 09
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the -v option to grep to invert the match so

```
grep uploaded file | grep -v 09
```

will do what you want. This finds the lines that contain uploaded which are passed piped into a grep command to ignore lines with 09 in them.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't using `grep` - but anytime I have a need that requires more than a basic `grep`, I turn to my favorite, `sed`. Certainly any time I have to chain `grep` commands together...

Use this command to do it:

```
sed -n '/09/d; /uploaded/p' file
```

Just one single command (not two).

Answer (score 2):

Try simply:

```
( grep -v 09 | grep uploaded ) < file
```

Example:

```
$ cat file
1 uploaded 09
2 09
3 uploaded
4 text
$ ( grep -v 09 | grep uploaded ) < file
3 uploaded
```